# iis server deployment wierd loop

Tags: asp.net, iis

I created deployment package of my site when I try to use it I get the following error:

The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

and the adress bar looks like this.this doens't happen in visual studio

```
http://localhost/MyServer/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMyServer%2fLogin.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fMyServer%252fLogin.aspx%253fReturnUrl%253d%25252fMyServer%25252fLogin.aspx%25253fReturnUrl%25253d%2525252fMyServer%2525252fLogin.aspx%2525253fReturnUrl%2525253d%252525252fMyServer%252525252fLogin.aspx%252525253fReturnUrl%252525253d%25252525252fMyServer%25252525252fLogin.aspx%25252525253fReturnUrl%25252525253d%2525252525252fMyServer%2525252525252fLogin.aspx%2525252525253fReturnUrl%2525252525253d%252525252525252fMyServer%252525252525252fLogin.aspx%252525252525253fReturnUrl%252525252525253d%25252525252525252fMyServer%25252525252525252fLogin.aspx%25252525252525253fReturnUrl%25252525252525253d%2525252525252525252fMyServer%2525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%2525252525252525253fReturnUrl%2525252525252525253d%252525252525252525252fMyServer%252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%252525252525252525253d%25252525252525252525252fMyServer%25252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%25252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253d%2525252525252525252525252fMyServer%2525252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%2525252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253d%252525252525252525252525252fMyServer%252525252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%252525252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253d%25252525252525252525252525252fMyServer%25252525252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%25252525252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253d%2525252525252525252525252525252fMyServer%2525252525252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%2525252525252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253d%252525252525252525252525252525252fMyServer%252525252525252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%252525252525252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253d%25252525252525252525252525252525252fMyServer%25252525252525252525252525252525252fLogin.aspx%25252525252525252525252525252525253fReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253d%2525252525252525252525252525252525252fMyServer%2525252525252525252525252525252525252f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have circular navigation. Please give code of `page load` event of `login.aspx` and the 2nd page which you are accessing.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hunch: it might be that your login page is not accessible for anonymous users. So it redirects to the login page, that in turn redirects to the login page.

Have a look at the web.config to set the proper access rights.

```
<location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your solution in Visual Studio has been built from one of the templates that has some sort of forms - based authentication built in. I'm pretty sure that you can disable this in the web.config.